# ASP.NET Output Cache Provider for Redis doesn't store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, outputcache

I am not sure how to troubleshoot it but I am trying to implement ASP.NET Output Cache via Redis Output cache provider.

We have Redis server (non-azure) set up and I can store cache for general usage.
However, when I try to setup ASP.NET output cache, it doesn't seem to save anything to cache!

I have installed Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider via Nuget.
Web.Config is set up with following:

```
<caching>
      <outputCache defaultProvider="MyRedisOutputCache">
        <providers>
          <add name="MyRedisOutputCache" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider" host="ServerName" port="6464" accessKey="PasswordToRedis" />
        </providers>
      </outputCache>
</caching>
```

The MVC controller is setup with OutputCache attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
        public JsonResult GetLookupData()
```

When I check the Redis, I don't see any OutputCache being stored.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to debug why it is not storing anything in cache?

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-web-app-howto , is cache PING command working from your web application ?

Comment: I should mention that neither app or the cache servers are on Azure. None are. Besides that, I am able to utilise Redis Cache using the normal caching method within the code. However, if I choose to use the OutputCacheProvider for Output caching, I doesn't store anything.

Comment: Can you try to change your web.config as per this post ? https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching/issues/35

Comment: I've tried it with the extra parameter on type and it is still not working. No errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this was really silly.

When you install RedisOutputCacheProvider via Nuget, you will get this small doco in your app/web.config:

```
<!-- For more details check https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki --><!-- Either use 'connectionString' OR 'settingsClassName' and 'settingsMethodName' OR use 'host','port','accessKey','ssl','connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds' and 'operationTimeoutInMilliseconds'. --><!-- 'databaseId' and 'applicationName' can be used with both options. --><!--
          <add name="MyRedisOutputCache" 
            host = "127.0.0.1" [String]
            port = "" [number]
            accessKey = "" [String]
            ssl = "false" [true|false]
            databaseId = "0" [number]
            applicationName = "" [String]
            connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" [number]
            operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000" [number]
            connectionString = "<Valid StackExchange.Redis connection string>" [String]
            settingsClassName = "<Assembly qualified class name that contains settings method specified below. Which basically return 'connectionString' value>" [String]
            settingsMethodName = "<Settings method should be defined in settingsClass. It should be public, static, does not take any parameters and should have a return type of 'String', which is basically 'connectionString' value.>" [String]
            loggingClassName = "<Assembly qualified class name that contains logging method specified below>" [String]
            loggingMethodName = "<Logging method should be defined in loggingClass. It should be public, static, does not take any parameters and should have a return type of System.IO.TextWriter.>" [String]
            redisSerializerType = "<Assembly qualified class name that implements Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer>" [String]
          />
```

It indicates the default value for "ssl" would be false.
However, reading through the code itself, it is actually defaulted to **true**.

So explicitly setting **ssl** to **false** have fixed it.

**EDIT**

Oh and I had to downgrade RedisOutputCacheProvider to 1.7.5.

3.0.1 didn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have mine working on local host without the SSL setting. In production I require it, but on mine it is part of the connectionstring (that I was given by my Redis hosting service).

The reason it was not working and you had to downgrade RedisOutputCacheProvider to 1.7.5 is because you are using Exchange.Redis.Strongname.dll (version 1.2.6)

As per this issue, Redis no longer requires a strongname because the base version is now strong named.
https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/107

So to use RedisOutputCacheProvider v3.0.144 you need to uninstall Exchange.Redis.Strongname.dll (version 1.2.6) and install Exchange.Redis.dll (version 2.0.601) via Nuget